# C# cant read xml in dataset

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

I just figuered out how to read my XML in the dataset.
Everything worked fine and after I started with encryption and decryption the ReadXML stopped working.

```
FTP.DownloadFile();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
String encrypted = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\lagerbestand.xml");
//String decrypted = StringCipher.DecryptString(encrypted, "XXXXX");
//MessageBox.Show(decrypted);
dataSet.ReadXml(encrypted);
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

The dataSet.ReadXML(encrypted); gives me an exception.

> Illegal letters in the path.

The path is correct, the String encrypted is also filled.
The encrypted String looks like the following:

```
"<NewDataSet>\r\n  <Table1>\r\n    <Artikelname>1</Artikelname>\r\n    <Artikelnummer>2</Artikelnummer>\r\n    <Lieferant>3</Lieferant>\r\n    <Bestand>4</Bestand>\r\n    <Artikelbeschreibung>5</Artikelbeschreibung>\r\n    <Min-Lagermenge>6</Min-Lagermenge>\r\n    <Einkauf>7</Einkauf>\r\n    <Verkauf>8</Verkauf>\r\n  </Table1>\r\n</NewDataSet>"
```

Comment: Is `StringCipher` a class from the .NET framework or is it [this](http://dwsim.inforside.com.br/api_help/html/M_DWSIM_SharedClasses_EncryptString_StringCipher_Decrypt.htm) class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadXML expects a file path

You should try this way

```cs
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
String encrypted = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\lagerbestand.xml");
//String decrypted = StringCipher.DecryptString(encrypted, "BeRo-0sT:De0asdnjkinu786*!");
//MessageBox.Show(decrypted);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(encrypted);
dataSet.ReadXml(sr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The method expects a file path not the actual xml.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=netframework-4.8

This should work:

```
dataSet.ReadXML(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\lagerbestand.xml");
```